# guzzle on azure to get all virtual hosts

Tags: php, azure, guzzle

I have working code on Postman and I can get all virtual hosts,
but when Im doing on the PHP with Guzzle it gives me trouble.
First part of code I get it where I get bearer token, but then to get list of virtual hosts it gives me error.

here is my code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request(
        'POST',
        "https://login.microsoftonline.com/".$tenant_id."/oauth2/token",
        Array(
            'form_params' => Array(
                'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',
                'client_id'     => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                'resource'      => 'https://management.core.windows.net/',
            )
        )
    );

    $body = $res->getBody();

    $stringBody = $body;
    $body_json = json_decode($stringBody);

    $r = $client->request(
        'GET',
        'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'.$subscriptionId.'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01', [
        ['headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$body_json->access_token
            ]
        ],
        'debug' => true
    ]);
```

and error:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/myid", error="invalid_token", error_description="The authentication failed because of missing 'Authorization' header."
```

I don't see why it doesn't want to connect

UPDATE: THIS WORKS, but with CURL

```
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer ". $body_json->access_token;
    $ch = curl_init('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'.$subscriptionId.'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

UPDATE: 
listing Virtual machines don't work, it gives me empty results, do I need to grant another access to be able to do this?
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'.$subscriptionId.'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code to request:

```
 ['headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $body_json->access_token
            ]
```

Comment: that didn't work :(
Right now I have token, but do you have answer to this:
UPDATE: listing Virtual machines don't work, it gives me empty results, do I need to grant another access to be able to do this? https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/'.$subscriptionId.'/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2017-12-01